# How do decibels scale with wave amplitude?

Tags: amplitude

I know the decibel scale is logarithmic in nature.

Given that at 1V amplitude the power of the sound generated by this wave is 80dB, what would the dB be for the wave with amplitude 0.4V?

I'm trying to figure out how the dB scales with wave amplitude. In my application, the "voltage" varies between 1 and -1 (audio signal).

I found this voltage-db equation:

$$N_\text{dB}=10\log_{10}\left( \frac{V^2_2}{V^2_1}\right)\\
=20\log_{10}\left( \frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)$$

However, I don't think this equation is directly applicable to my situation.

Is there a formula I can use for converting voltage to db (given the db at a particular voltage, like above).

Comment: "I found this voltage-db equation" yes, that is the one correct equation. Could you elaborate on why you think it's not applicable to your situation?

Comment: @MarcusMüller $70 = 20\log_{10}(1/?)$

Comment: How much is the decrease from 15V to 6V in dB - you've calculated it correctly to be -7.96 dB. Then 6V corresponds to 70 - 7.96 ~= 62 dB SPL (I am guessing it's SPL you are talking about since you mentioned sound).

Comment: @jojek Read the question. I did not calculate 7.96 anywhere

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi It's just been edited. You've asked the question: *Given that at 15V amplitude the amplitude of the sound generated by this wave is 70dB, what would the dB be for the wave with amplitude 6V?* so I placed the comment to answer this particular point.

Comment: @jojek The edit makes no difference; in the original question your calculations are also wrong

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi I wasn't aware you are not the author of calculations in the graph. Calculations are certainly correct. If 15V gives 70 dB SPL then 6V will yield  62 dB SPL.

Comment: @jojek it's a coincidence that theyre also using 70db. Your calculations themselves are wrong.

Comment: @jojek I removed the image and changed the to 80dB. Now your answer makes no sense. You need to use the proper formula like I did in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your problem it seems that there is a misunderstanding between dB and dBm. When we talk about the power ratios between signals we will express the difference in dB while when we will express the power of the signal we will be interested in the power in dBm which is none other than the power of the signal in question compared to 1mW.

Which leads me to say that you better calculate the power in dBm for your full scale signal and come and rely on this result to calculate your other values.

Full scale power : \begin{equation} P_{full} (dBm) = 30 + 10log_{10}(\frac{V_{RMS}I_{RMS}}{1W})\end{equation}

For the second one :

\begin{equation} P_2 (dBm)= P_{full} - 10log_{10} (0.4^2) \approx P_{full} - 7.958\end{equation}

Comment: This is not an electrical engineering application (I'm speaking about audio signals).